# automatically add points between each number in editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm making a android app, but I have a question, How I can automatically add points to insert hyphens and numbers EditText.

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Example:

Im insert 123456789
and EditText should show 12.234.5678-9
or when you are inserting, add the dots and dashes

Comment: Can you be clear than this? In what way you should place dots and hyphens?

Comment: You could have a look at `DecimalFormat` ([http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)) and (like CFlex said) you should format your Decimals via a `Listener`

Comment: when I add an EditText these numbers should be separated by points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`addTextChangedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) method. You can add a listener to your edittext and then modify the text inside directly to add your points, using [`afterTextChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29) method.

I hope this will help you :)